# permanently source in terminal (Mac OS)

Tags: bash, macos, macos-catalina

this is probably a very basic question. I am using the bash shell still (Catalina). And I downloaded gromacs. Every time I open a new terminal window I first have to put

```
source /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC
```

in first, otherwise I will just get command not found.

How can I permanently source this so that I don't have to reenter it all the time?

I tried editing the /etc/paths file but that didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried sourcing it from bashrc?

Comment: do you mean the .bash_profile file? I tried adding export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC" there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still using the `bash` shell on `macOS`, all you have to do is:

Put the line:

```
source /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC
```

at the end in `.bash_profile`.

`.bash_profile` is in home directory, so you can open it like:

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

**Why .bash_profile?**

`.bash_profile` is executed whenever a login interactive shell starts and on mac, every interactive shell is a login shell by default.

If in case you switch to `zsh`, instead of `.bash_profile`, I think `.zlogin` should be used.

But that would depend entirely on your need. Read about [zsh configuration files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout) in case you ever need that.

Comment: can't believe I didn't try this! Thank you so much :)

Comment: There's also `.zprofile` (which runs *before* `.zshrc` rather than *after*, which is when `.zlogin` is sourced). To be honest, I'm not really sure what the rationale for this is. (Is there really a pressing need for bracketing `.zshrc` like this?)

Comment: @chepner, as he was having issues before, I thought in case he switches to `zsh`, `.zlogin` should be less likely to create issues as it is executed after `.zprofile` and `.zshrc` and effects caused by it would be the final ones. Although that's just a general case, and its possible that in his case `.zprofile/rc` may be better. `.zlogin` was more of a side-note, but now as you have mentioned, I will attach some additional links to the answer to clarify that too.